# The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, screen-orientation, dart-null-safety

I Hello, I need help in my code, why I am getting this error, I copied the code from another project but there is no error there.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
dynamic screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
dynamic screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
ScreenUtil.init(
    BoxConstraints(maxWidth: screenWidth, maxHeight: screenHeight),
    designSize: const Size(360, 690),
    orientation: Orientation.portrait);

return Scaffold(
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScreenUtil.init`'s  1st argument is of type `BuildContext`.

```dart
    ScreenUtil.init(
      context,
      deviceSize: Size(screenWidth, screenHeight),
      designSize: const Size(360, 690),
      orientation: Orientation.portrait,
    );
```

Comment: but why was it working in old project?

Comment: Seems like `Break Change:510` you can check the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil/changelog) for older version it will work, while you are using later package version you need to provide context in this case.